# How can i use Myfaces 2.3, Primefaces Elite 7.0.4 & Extensions and Omnifaces 3.3 together in a SpringBoot application?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, primefaces, myfaces, omnifaces

I want to split an existing JavaEE "monolith" into seperate microservice 
parts and after a little bit researching i want to switch to Spring-Boot
instead of using Mojarra 2.3, Primefaces 7.0.4 including Primefaces Extensions, Omnifaces 3.3 on a wildfly application server 16.0.0.
The build was currently made with maven and i want to keep that way.

I am new to Spring-Boot, so is there currently a concrete description/example
using MyFaces 2.3, Primefaces 7.0.4 (Installed in locale repository only) and Omnifaces 3.3 together ? I know that i need MyFaces in version 2.3 to use the latest omnifaces version which is currently used by the project ...

I have also seen that the most configurations of Spring-Boot are made with 
JoinJaces - but i don't know how to do that with it because the primefaces library is the buyed and commercial one and not the open version ...

Comment: Are you sure, 1000% sure you NEED microservices? Since of you ask the question you ask, I suspect you have become a victim of something that might be usefull in some cases but not in all. It is overly hyped imo. And please read [ask], your question is offtopic for SO

Comment: I use this exact combination.  Use JoinFaces for Spring Boot: http://joinfaces.org/

Comment: @Melloware:
Do you have an example on how i can do that ?
I can't found this combination on joinfaces.

Comment: @Kukeltje: Yes, i am new here but i currently don't know what your problem with the question is because it seems that you understand it ?
So if you criticize, then please explain.

And i want to switch to SpringBoot because it seems to be an easier way for me splitting a big monolith  into some smaller maintable parts. 
I also need to start the WebApplication without always handling the updates/configurations of the webserver or at a later state ship it by using docker.

Comment: @joy77 yes they have this app you simply plug in PrimeFaces, OmniFaces etc and it generates the Spring Boot app for you with all the configs.  https://joinfaces-example.herokuapp.com/starter.jsf

Comment: @Melloware: That's more than perfect for starting with SpringBoot !
**Thank you very much !**

Answer (score 2):

JoinFaces is the way to go: http://joinfaces.org/

You can use their starter app to configure Spring boot for PrimeFaces, OmniFaces, MyFaces etc. See: https://joinfaces-example.herokuapp.com/starter.jsf

It will generate you a starter project with everything wired up.